# Formulário via method PUT não esta enviando os dados a um service restEasy

Tags: java, angularjs, resteasy

Estou enviando um formulário via Ajax, meu front é feito em AngularJS. Capturo as informações do formulário e envio para um service que é em Java RestReasy. Porém ele chega Nullo! Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Em meu controlador esta assim:

```
var req = {
         method: 'PUT',
         url: "api/empresa/"+appCtrl.userLogado.id,


         data: {empresa: empresa} ,

         headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        };


        $http(req).then(function (response) {

            iziToast.success({
                title: 'Sucesso!',
                message: 'Atualização realizada com sucesso!',

                onClose: function(){
                    $("#divload").hide();
                    $("#loader").hide();



                }


            });

        }, function (error) {

            iziToast.warning({
                message: 'Infelizmente não foi possível fazer a atualização',
                onClose: function() {

                    $("#divload").hide();
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    $("#login-box").show();
                    window.location.href = 'index.jsp';
                }

            });

        });
```

Em meu rest esta assim:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
@PermitAll
public Response update(@PathParam("id") Long id ,@FormParam("empresa") String empresaJson){
```

[RESOLVIDO]
No javascript coloquei JSON.stringify(JSON.parse()) e resolveu o problema!

Comment: Você debugou "empresa" no JS antes de fazer a requisição para ver se obteve algum valor para mandar?

Comment: Sim, ele ta normal no JS. Porém no resteasy ele não chega....